# Generating TDB Dataset from archive containing N-TRIPLES files

Tags: bash, rdf, jena, tdb

Apologies, in advance, for a possible duplicate.

I have an archive containing 117,426 files (each in the `N-TRIPLES` format) that I wish to load into the default graph of a TDB dataset. Due to the large number of files, I need to be able to perform this import without manually selecting individual files for upload.

I am in Bash, with Jena and Fuseki distributions at my disposal.

If possible, I want to avoid the worst-case scenario of just writing a java application to do this. If I have to write a java application for this, what hooks exist in RIOT/TDB to perform programmatic bulk-loading?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As a genenral comment, one way is to concatenate the N-Triples files to generate one single file.

You can load many files at once with either `tdbloader` or `tdbloader2`.

```
tdbloader --loc DB ... your files ...
```

The 117,426 may strain you OS for a single command line invocation.  You can pipe the files into `tdbloader` (it's just like concatenating the files first)

```
... | tdbloader --loc DB -- -
```

where `...` is some way to get bash to cat the files (possible from a subshell).

e.g. (you'll need to adjust to file all 117,426 files):

```
( for x in data*.nt
  do
    cat $x 
  done
) | tdbloader --loc DB -- -
```

Comment: Worked perfectly without modification (31,242,719 triples loaded in 1,191.49 seconds). In this scenario I was able to unzip the archive in order to support this approach.