# Piping bzip2 output into tdbloader2 (apache-jena) gives "File does not exist"

Tags: bash, pipe, jena

I want to pipe the output from bzip2 and use it as an input to fill a TDB database using tbdloader2 from apache-jena-3.9.0.

I already found 
[Generating TDB Dataset from archive containing N-TRIPLES files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25730414/generating-tdb-dataset-from-archive-containing-n-triples-files/25731085#25731085?newreg=f9531150e2814defac44cd464e9c26f8)
but the proposed solution there did not work for me.

```
bzip2 -dc test.ttl.bz2 | tdbloader2 --loc=/pathto/TDBdatabase_test -- -
```

produces

```
20:08:01 INFO -- TDB Bulk Loader Start
20:08:01 INFO Data Load Phase
20:08:01 INFO Got 1 data files to load
20:08:01 INFO Data file 1: /home/user/-
File does not exist: /home/user/-
20:08:01 ERROR Failed during data phase
```

Similar results I got with with (inspired by https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/16990/using-data-read-from-a-pipe-instead-than-from-a-file-in-command-options)

```
bzip2 -dc test.ttl.bz2 | tdbloader2 --loc=/pathto/TDBdatabase_test /dev/stdin 
20:34:45 INFO -- TDB Bulk Loader Start
20:34:45 INFO Data Load Phase
20:34:45 INFO Got 1 data files to load
20:34:45 INFO Data file 1: /proc/16256/fd/pipe:[92062]
File does not exist: /proc/16256/fd/pipe:[92062]
20:34:45 ERROR Failed during data phase
```

and

```
bzip2 -dc test.ttl.bz2 | tdbloader2 --loc=/pathto/TDBdatabase_test /dev/fd/0 
20:34:52 INFO -- TDB Bulk Loader Start
20:34:52 INFO Data Load Phase
20:34:52 INFO Got 1 data files to load
20:34:52 INFO Data file 1: /proc/16312/fd/pipe:[97432]
File does not exist: /proc/16312/fd/pipe:[97432]
20:34:52 ERROR Failed during data phase
```

unpacking the bz2 file manually and then adding it works fine:

```
bzip2 -d test.ttl.bz2
tdbloader2 --loc=/pathto/TDBdatabase_test test.ttl
```

Would be great if someone could point me in the right direction.

Comment: Your question is better suited to [Super User](http://superuser.com/tour). [Stack Overflow is a question and answer site for professional and enthusiast programmers](http://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

tdbloader2 accepts bz2 compressed files on the command line:

```
tdbloader2 --loc=/pathto/TDBdatabase_test test.ttl.bz2
```

It doesn't accept input from a pipe - and if it did, then it would not know the syntax is Turtle which it gets from the file extension.

Comment: thank you. works. I didn't think about it as feeding zipped files didn't work when using fuseki.

Comment: bz2 and gz are a single file compression tools; zip is an archive where the individual entries have separate names. c.f. tar The names matter for reading files to get the syntax. zip files could be supported; it is unpacking and reading each file but the base URI is going to be weird.  (yes, gz can have several files, but it isn't an archive as such.)