# Add basic value to Ontology individuals @Jena

Tags: java, mysql, jena, ontology, preloading

I have an Ontology with some Classes and everything setup to run. What is a good way to fill it up with Individuals and Data?? In Short do a one-way Mapping from Database (as Input) to an Ontology.

```
public class Main {

static String SOURCE =  "http://www.umingo.de/ontology/bento.owl";

static String NS =  SOURCE+"#";

 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    OntModel model = ModelFactory.createOntologyModel( OntModelSpec.OWL_MEM );

    // read the RDF/XML file
    model.read(SOURCE);

    OntologyPreLoader loader = new OntologyPreLoader();
    model = loader.init(model);

    model.write(System.out,"RDF/XML");

 }
}
```

My Preloader has a Method init with the goal to copy data from a database into the ontology. Here is the Excerpt.

```
 public OntModel init(OntModel model) throws SQLException{

          Resource r = model.getResource( Main.NS + "Tag" );
          Property tag_name = model.createProperty(Main.NS + "Tag_Name");
          OntClass tag = r.as( OntClass.class );
          // statements allow to issue SQL queries to the database
          statement = connect.createStatement();
          // resultSet gets the result of the SQL query
          resultSet = statement
              .executeQuery("select * from niuu.tags");
            // resultSet is initialised before the first data set
            while (resultSet.next()) {
              // it is possible to get the columns via name
              // also possible to get the columns via the column number
              // which starts at 1
              // e.g., resultSet.getSTring(2);
              String id = resultSet.getString("id");
              String name = resultSet.getString("name");

              Individual tag_tmp = tag.createIndividual(Main.NS+"Tag_"+id);
              tag_tmp.addProperty(tag_name,name);
              System.out.println("id: " + id);
              System.out.println("name: " + name);
            }

          return model;
      }
```

Everything is working, but I feel really unsure about this way to preload ontologies. Also every Individual should get its own ID so that i can match it with the database at a later point. 
Can i simply define a Property ID and add it to every Individual?

I thought about Adding ID to "Thing" as it is the most basic Type in OWL ontologies.

Comment: Btw, have you tried to map your data, then store the triples in a triples store? Then you would not need your original database. You could use Jena TDB for this purpose.

Comment: I have played around with some of the database and already need a java heapspace of 3,4 GB. I dont think i will store the ontology tripples as a file. but thanks for the suggestion

Comment: Note that TDB uses memory-mapped file IO and intelligently pages its indexes. TDB is slower for small datasets that you could otherwise store in memory, but it continues to operate when your dataset grows too large to store in memory. I've run TDB up to 27 million triples with only 4 GB memory. TDB's indexing requires a `lot` of disk space however.

Answer (score 1):

At first sight it seems ok. One tip is to try convert the Jena model into a RDF serialization and run it through Protégé to get a more clear picture on how your ontology mapping looks like.

You can definitely make your own property to describe the id of every individual. 
Beneath is an example on how you can create a similar property in turtle format.(I did not add the prefixes for OWL and rdfs since they are some common) 
You can add this in Jena aswell if needed. (or load this into your model in Jena.)

```
@prefix you: <your domain> .
you:dbIdentificator a owl:DatatypeProperty  .
you:dbIdentificator rdfs:label "<Your database identifcator>"@en  .
you:dbIdentificator rdfs:comment "<Some valuable information if needed>"@en  .
you:dbIdentificator rdfs:isDefinedBy <your domain>  .
you:dbIdentificator rdfs:domain owl:Thing  .
```

You could also add owl:Thing to every resource, but that is not the best practice because it is a vague definition of a resource. I would look around for vocabularies that defines more what the resource is. Take a look at [GoodRelations](http://www.heppnetz.de/ontologies/goodrelations/v1.html). It is a very good defined vocabulary that can describe information even though it is not for commercial use. Especially check out the classes there.

Hope that answered some of your question.

Answer (score 1):

Programatically generating URIs is always somewhat unsettling. If you have Guava, use [`Preconditions`](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/PreconditionsExplained) to make some fail-fast assertions about what's coming out of the database (so that your code will let you know if it gets out of alignment with your schema). Use the JDK's [`URLEncoder`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URLEncoder.html) to ensure that the `id` you get from the database is converted to a URI-friendly format (Note that if your data contains characters that cannot be printed in xml and have no percent encoding, you'll need to manually handle them).

For your property/column values, use explicitly create the literal. This makes it very clear whether you are using plain literals, language literals, or typed literals:

```java
// If things can have multiple names in multiple languages, for example
tag_tmp.addProperty(tag_name,model.createTypedLiteral(name, "en"));
```

Note that you may not wish to define your schema so that it implies things about `owl:Thing`, because that would have implications outside of your domain. Instead, define a domain-specific notion like a `:DatabaseResource`. Set the domains of your properties to be that and it's subclasses rather than thing. This way the use of your property implies that the subject with within your domain, rather than simply an owl individual (which is implied by the domain of `owl:DatatypeProperty` anyway).

**EDIT**: It's absolutely acceptable to create a representation of the database's unique ID and place it into the RDF model. If you are using owl2, you can define an [`OWL-2 Key`](http://www.w3.org/TR/owl2-syntax/#Keys) on that property for your `:DatabaseResource`s  and keep the same semantics that you had in the database.

**EDIT**: Noting a portion of your post on the Jena mailing list:

> I have a huge MYSQL-Database for read only purpose and want to extract some Data into the Ontology.

I would highly recommend using the [TDB Java API](https://jena.apache.org/documentation/tdb/java_api.html) to construct a `Dataset` that backed by your disk. I've worked on very large database exports before, and it's quite possible that your data size won't be tractable otherwise. TDB's indexing requires a lot of disk space, but the memory-mapped IO makes it very difficult to kill due to OOM errors. Finally, once you have constructed the database on disk, you won't have to perform this expensive import operation again (or could at least optimize it).

If you find database creation times to be prohibitive, then you may with to utilize the bulk loader in creative ways. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25915064/2528639) has an example of using the bulk loader from java.

Comment: hmm i like your idea. now i am thinking about a superclass DatabaseEntity and all Subclasses should have at least a DatabaseIdentifier. That way i am keeping "Thing" clean and can later have classes without an ID.

Comment: You also can have orthogonal sections of your class hierarchy. For example, `:person1` may have been extracted from the database while `:person2` was added to your persistent data later. You could add both `foaf:Person` and `:DatabaseEntity` as types for `:person1` but only add `foaf:Person` for `:person2`. That way you don't have to assume that your entire hierarchy extends `:DatabaseEntity` as your knowledge base evolves.